# Python replace sub string containing hex digit

Tags: python, string

How can I replace the substring value (the hex value 0x20E00) with a new hex value in python?

```
 <d:var name="Length" value="0x20E00"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression and [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '<d:var name="Length" value="0x20E00"/>'
>>> re.sub(r'0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+', '0xdeadbeef', s)
'<d:var name="Length" value="0xdeadbeef"/>'
```

That said, if you're working with XML, you're much better off using an [XML parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) with [`look behind`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
re.sub(r'(?<=value=\").*(?=\")', 'new hex value',s)
'<d:var name="Length" value="new hex value"/>'
```